# Question regarding surjectivity of a nonzero function satisfying $ f \big( a + 2 f ( a ) f ( b ) \big) = f ( a ) + 2 a f ( b ) $

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I was practicing that how to prove surjectivity of functions in a functional equation and I came across the following question.

> Let $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a function such that
> $$ f \big( a + 2 f ( a ) f ( b ) \big) = f ( a ) + 2 a f ( b ) $$
> for all $ a , b \in \mathbb R $. Also, suppose that $ f $ is not the all-zero function. Prove that $ f $ is surjective.

I really don't have any idea about how to prove it. A pedantic and easiest possible proof will be highly appreciated and would be helpful.

Comment: You might want to look at https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1624578p10180515

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that
$$ f \big( a + 2 f ( a ) f ( b ) \big) = f ( a ) + 2 a f ( b ) \tag 0 \label 0 $$
for all $ a , b \in \mathbb R $ which is not the constant zero function. Setting $ a = b = - \frac 1 2 $ in \eqref{0} gives
$$ f \left( - \frac 1 2 + 2 f \left( - \frac 1 2 \right) ^ 2 \right) = 0 \text . \tag 1 \label 1 $$
For any $ a \in \mathbb R $ with $ f ( a ) = 0 $, \eqref{0} gives $ a f ( b ) = 0 $. In case $ a \ne 0 $, that shows that $ f $ is the constant zero function, contrary to the assumption. Thus such $ a $ must be equal to $ 0 $, which by \eqref{1} not only shows that $ f ( 0 ) = 0 $, but also $ - \frac 1 2 + 2 f \left( - \frac 1 2 \right) ^ 2 = 0 $, or equivalently $ f \left( - \frac 1 2 \right) = - \frac k 2 $ where $ k ^ 2 = 1 $, i.e. $ k \in \{ - 1 , 1 \} $. Now, setting $ b = - \frac 1 2 $ in \eqref{0} shows that
$$ f \big( a - k f ( a ) \big) = f ( a ) - k a \text , \tag 2 \label 2 $$
while plugging $ a = - \frac 1 2 $ in \eqref{0} gives
$$ f \left( - \frac 1 2 - k f ( b ) \right) = - \frac k 2 - f ( b ) \text . \tag 3 \label 3 $$
By setting $ a = \frac 1 2 $ in \eqref{2} we have $ f \Big( \frac 1 2 - k f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) \Big) = f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) - \frac k 2 $, which shows that letting $ b = \frac 1 2 - k f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) $ in \eqref{3} we get
$$ f \Bigg( - k f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) \Bigg) = - f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) \text . \tag 4 \label 4 $$
By plugging $ a = \frac 1 2 $ and $ b = - k f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) $ in \eqref{0} and using \eqref{4} we get $ f \Big( \frac 1 2 - 2 f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) \Big) = 0 $, which means that we must have $ f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) ^ 2 = \frac 1 4 $, or equivalently $ f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) = \pm \frac k 2 $. But by \eqref{4}, $ f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) = - \frac k 2 $ leads to $ f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) = - f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) $, contradicting $ f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) ^ 2 = \frac 1 4 $. Thus we have $ f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) = \frac k 2 $.

Now, assume that for some $ c \in \mathbb R $ we have $ f ( c ) = - k c $. By \eqref{3} we have $ f \left( - \frac 1 2 + c \right) = k \left( - \frac 1 2 + c \right) $. Then, setting $ x = \frac 1 2 $ and $ y = - \frac 1 2 + c $ in \eqref{0}, we get $ f ( c ) = k c $, which means that we must have $ c = 0 $. By \eqref{2}, we know that for any $ a \in \mathbb R $, letting $ c = a - k f ( a ) $ we have $ f ( c ) = - k c $, and therefore we must have $ k f ( a ) = a $, or equivalently $ f ( a ) = k a $. Hence, $ f $ has to either be the identity function or its opposite. It's straightforward to verify that those are both surjective solutions.

---

\eqref{0} is a variant of the functional equation
$$ f \big( a + f ( a ) f ( b ) \big) = f ( a ) + a f ( b ) \text , $$
which has appeared in *The American Mathematical Monthly*, with an official answer [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30037564?refreqid=excelsior%3A4faa02c845c6fa6b38b1bec75a0a9268). This question has been asked many times on AoPS, and you can for example find solutions [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h88456p526193), [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1259896p6534316), [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1138359p5330592), [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h292835) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h132331p749029). The official answer and several others first prove surjectivity and then use that to characterize the solutions of the equation. The answer I gave above is similar to the one in the last linked page. Not only it doesn't appeal to surjectivity first, but also it's shorter and simpler than all others.

---

*Wu Wei Chao, and The University of Louisiana at Lafayette Math Club*, [**Two Functional Equations: 11053**](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30037564), *The American Mathematical Monthly* **112** (2005), no. 7, 661--662.

Comment: None of the links in your notes (below the line, journal article included) actually proves surjectivity **first** (or explicitly at all, because they all end with finding the solutions). Only the link in Sil's comment to the OP does.

Comment: @NickPavlov Thanks for noting. It seems that you're right. Since I posted this answer a long time ago, I don't remember why I've said so; but I guess that I had many more links to other posts on AOPS where they did prove surjectivity first, and ended up posting the above links which include non of them. I usually use approach0.xyz to search for posts related to questions here (especially those about functional equations), and often there are too many to give links to them all, and I end up choosing some of them.