# Find all nonconstant function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+2f(x)f(y))=f(x)+2xf(y)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find all nonconstant function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+2f(x)f(y))=f(x)+2xf(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion $f(x+2f(x)f(y))=f(x)+2xf(y)$.

$P(-\frac 12,-\frac 12)$ $\implies$ $f(-\frac 12+2f(-\frac 12)^2)=0$ and let $t=-\frac 12+2f(-\frac 12)^2$. Then $P(t,y)\Rightarrow 0=tf(y),\forall y\in \mathbb{R},i.e, t=0$. It implies that  $f(-\frac 12)^2=\frac 14$ Note that if $f$ is a solution of this problem then so $-f$. Therefore, WLOG, we may asume that $f(-1/2)=-1/2$ and $f(0)=0$.

$P(-\frac 12,x)$ $\implies$ $f(-\frac 12-f(x))=-\frac 12-f(x)$

$P(-\frac 12, -\frac 12-f(x))$ $\implies$ $f(f(x))=f(x)$

I wonder if we can prove that $f$ is surjective?
Somebody help me. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question regarding surjectivity of a nonzero function satisfying $ f \big( a + 2 f ( a ) f ( b ) \big) = f ( a ) + 2 a f ( b ) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3936813/229831)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: as pointed out by Mohsen Shahriari, this solution is wrong. The correct place to go is his solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936813/question-regarding-surjectivity-of-a-nonzero-function-satisfying-f-big-a-2).**

Hint: apply $f$ to both sides.

Solution:

> Apply $f$ to both sides, from $f(f(x))=f(x)$ we get $$x+2f(x)f(y)=f(f(x)+2xf(y))$$ Let $y=0$, so $$x=f(f(x)).$$ Now it's clear.

Comment: This seems to be incorrect. It seems that you've mistakenly equated $ f \bigl ( f ( t ) \bigr ) $ with $ t $ instead of $ f ( t ) $, where $ t = x + 2 f ( x ) f ( y ) $. The correct conclusion would be
$$ f \bigl ( f ( x ) + 2 x f ( y ) \bigr ) = f \bigl ( x + 2 f ( x ) f ( y ) \bigr ) = f ( x ) + 2 x f ( y ) \text , $$
which doesn't seem to be on a promising path towards proving surjectivity.